# Function to calculate and plot arctanx

Tags: python, function

I need to write a function that can write and solve the inverse of tan for values that I input as two arrays. Sometimes the array on the denominator contains zero so always a division by zero occurs. I don't know how to get rid of the error and make the answer return pi/2 instead.

```
def deviation(x):

if capture(x)==True:
 for i in range(len(yvf)):
          theta=sp.arctan(xvf/yvf)   #xvf and yvf are two arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: write xvf[i] and yvf[i] to access the single elements of the arrays one after the other.

Secondly discern if yvf[i] equals zero or not:

```
if yvf[i] == 0:
    theta = math.pi/2.0
else:
    theta = sp.arctan(xvf[i]/yvf[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import numpy, I suggest using arctan2 instead of arctan ([see this doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#numpy.arctan2)). This function manages zero values in the 2nd argument.

If not, you can solve this problem with atan2 function of math library and zip built-in function :

```
import math

xvf = [0.,2.,2.]
yvf = [20.,0.,2.]

def arctan(xvf,yvf):
  return [math.atan2(x,y) for x,y in zip(xvf,yvf)]

print arctan(xvf,yvf)
```